# Entites count in dependency injection and Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

As a standard we make **'N'** controllers for **'N'** entities.
Let say i have two entities one for student and one for course, i have to add student and add course, if i make interface for class that do crud operations for Student and another interface for class that does crud operations for course , I have to pass object of those implemented classes for seperate controllers for both course and student

and in case i need object for implemented class of course in my student controller? 
actually we do not assign classes to interface in controllers directly
we bind them in Ninject.common file, where we describe that A interface use B class and C interface use D class.

Should i use two parameters in my first controller constructor?
Should i directly make object of class that implements second interface in my first controller ?
if you say i should use model binding, then how to add data in binded class D in my first controller through class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it depends.

If your application is small, with two entities in a single database, and you do minimal transformation or validation work on save,  I would say you should only have one repository class for access to both entities. This minimizes complexity.

However if you need to do a lot of work every time you save an entity (data clensing, validation, etc.) use separate data access classes which in turn invoke a single repository that handles actually saving and getting your entities.

As for where to initialize, always use dependency injection, never directly instantiate. Follow that rule until it seems silly, then break it.